# Jquery not getting current element value

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery 1.9 version to append the text box element with comma separation.
here is my jquerycode

```
var str=$("to1").val();
    $("#sup").on('change',function(){
        if($("#sup").val()!=""){
            if(str == undefined){
            //alert('here');
            str="";
            str+=$(this).val();
            $("#to1").val(str);
            }else{
            console.log(str);
            str+=","+$(this).val();
            $("#to1").val(str);
            }       
        }
    });
```

But when I delete one email id by backspace and select another email id then its append previous one.

here is my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7GFj5/1/

How can I append it with current email list

Answer (score 0):

The variable `str` must be declared within the `change` handler, the problem is any manual change done on the textfield will not update the `str` variable

```
$(function () {
    $("#sup").on('change', function () {
        var str = $("#to1").val();
        if ($("#sup").val() != "") {
            if (str == undefined) {
                //alert('here');
                str = "";
                str += $(this).val();
                $("#to1").val(str);
            } else {
                console.log(str);
                str += "," + $(this).val();
                $("#to1").val(str);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2DK9N/)

Comment: It working but I want to append the email id with comma like my example.

Comment: @user1567682 missed `#` in `var str = $("#to1").val();`

Answer (score 0):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GFj5/4/) also deals with the first item not needing a comma.

```
$('#sup').change( function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        if ($('#to1').val() != "")
            $('#to1').val($('#to1').val() + ', ' + $(this).val());
        else
            $('#to1').val($(this).val());
    }
});
```